# How can I separate an single entity into multiple classes with sequelize with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to setup a single table with another class as an attribute but is not another entity.

For example I have the user table and one of his attributes is the Hobby class, but hobby is not an entity. Hobby's attributes are part of the user table data.

The case is the following (it's a simplification of the major scene):

**Tables**

I have a two tables, User with this attributes:

```
id
name
age
hobby <- this is part of another class
skill_level <- this is part of another class
```

And Phone:

```
id
phone_number
user_id
```

**Classes**

User Class

```
import { Hobby } from './Hobby';
import { Phone } from './Phone';
import { Column, DataType, HasMany, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({ tableName: 'user_test', timestamps: false })
export class User extends Model<User> {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    field: 'id',
    defaultValue: true,
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({ field: 'name', type: DataType.STRING })
  name: string;

  @Column({ field: 'age', type: DataType.INTEGER })
  age: number;

  hobby: Hobby; // <- this is the one that I can't figure out how to define, hobby is 
  //not an entity, is part of the user table.

  @HasMany(() => Phone)
  phone: Phone[]; // <- this works perfect has phone is another entity
}
```

Hobby class (I'm quite sure this is wrong, but I haven't found any clue)

```
import { Column, Model, Table } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({ tableName: 'user_test', timestamps: false })
export class Hobby extends Model {
  @Column({ field: 'hobby' })
  hobby: string;

  @Column({ field: 'skill_level' })
  skillLevel: number;
}
```

Phone class (this one works fine)

```
import {
  BelongsTo,
  Column,
  DataType,
  ForeignKey,
  Model,
  Table,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { User } from './User';

@Table({ tableName: 'phone_test', timestamps: false })
export class Phone extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, field: 'id' })
  id: number;

  @Column({ field: 'phone_number', type: DataType.INTEGER })
  phoneNumber: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({ field: 'user_id' })
  userId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user: User;
}
```

I can make work the relationship with user-phone without any problem but i'm having quite a time trying to figure out how to make this relationship with "Hobby" the skill class.

I can do this in java with the *javax.persistence's @Embedded* decorator
[image]

But I couldn't find something like that with sequelize with typescript.

Comment: You can do something like that only with raw query and `nest` option otherwise you need to do this mapping yourself

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, I could get some results by changing the structure of the user-hobby to a single entity and applying a mapper. But I found something about Virtual fields for the issue that I mentioned on the post.
If I have some news about it I'll update the post.

Comment: Yes, you can use virtual fields but you still will have the original fields that you use to build `Hobby`